# Replacing redux provider with createProvider throws an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a system with context provider which is working properly for one store:

```
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux'
import sfc from './component'

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    host: ownProps.host
})

const ConnectedSfc = connect(mapStateToProps)(sfc)
export const AppMainView = props => (
    <Provider store={props.host.getStore()}>
        <ConnectedSfc host={props.host} />
    </Provider>
)
```

Now I'm trying to set my workspace to deal with two different stores,
So I've changed the provider according to [this](https://medium.com/@azizhk/create-multiple-redux-stores-b77b7359375f) guide:

```
import { connect, createProvider } from 'react-redux'
import sfc from './component'
import { STORE_KEY } from './constants'

const Provider = createProvider(STORE_KEY)
```

And set the `storeKey` to the connect options.

However, when I'm running the project (only with this small change), an error is thrown:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(sfc)".
Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(sfc)".
```

What am I doing wrong?